# Trigger mouseenter to center of image

Tags: jquery, html, css

**HTML**

```
<img src="xxxx.png"/>
```

**CSS**

```
div#centered-div {
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    width: 10px;
    height: 10px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
$.fancybox.open(getFancyArray(image), {
       afterShow: function () {
                var tpl = '<div id="centered-div"></div>';
                $(ui.fancyboxInner).append(tpl);
                $(ui.fancyboxInner).zoom({
                    callback: function () {
                     $(ui.fancyImage).trigger('mousemove');
                     $("centered-div").trigger('mouseenter');

                 }
             });
         },
   }
```

I am opening fancybox image,  once fancy shows the image, it will call afterShow event then zoom component will initiliaze image. after init I need to trigger hover effect to the image to handle hover effect.

The first problem was If I dont trigger mouseenter user should go out from container and go inside again to init zoom event

Zoom component :  (http://www.jacklmoore.com/zoom/)

What I need is triggering mouse enter just center of the image. By this I can start another method which expecting hover effect automatically

Comment: You could overlay the center of your image with a transparent div, and add the mouseenter to that div.

Comment: @Sirence I Exactly did this, but other component is expecting hover effect on image

Comment: Which other component? Could you show me it's code?

Comment: I am editing question

Comment: absolute center i mean intersectio of x and y or just height?

Comment: @MehmetErenYener I added an Edit with a working example, hope this helps you!

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this:

(Edit: Prettier Fiddle)

https://jsfiddle.net/zjxqLc8x/

```
$(img).mousemove(function(e){
    var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
    var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
    var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
});
```

With this you can get the position of the mouse every time the user is hovering over the image. With that, you can check if the mouse is within the part of the image you want (center in your case) and act accordingly.

Here is an example for changing the border color when you hover over the center of the image:

https://jsfiddle.net/zjxqLc8x/1/

```
//getting the center +-20px so the user is actually able to find it

var minheight = $("#imageholder").height() / 2 -20;
var minwidth = $("#imageholder").width() / 2 -20;
var maxheight = $("#imageholder").height() / 2 +20;
var maxwidth = $("#imageholder").width() / 2 +20;


//check position on hover

$('#imageholder').mousemove(function(e){
var parentOffset = $(this).parent().offset(); 
   var relX = e.pageX - parentOffset.left;
   var relY = e.pageY - parentOffset.top;
   $('#mousex').html(relX);
   $('#mousey').html(relY);


   //if the mouse is in the correct position, we change the border color

   if ((relX >= minwidth) && (relX <= maxwidth) && (relY >=minheight) && (relY <= maxheight)) {
       $('#imageholder').css('border', '1px solid red');
   } else {
       $('#imageholder').css('border', '1px solid blue');
   }

});
```